# How to resolve DNS lookup error when trying to run example microservice application using minikube

Tags: kubernetes, dns, minikube, skaffold

Dear StackOverflow community!

I am trying to run the https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/microservices-demo locally on minikube, so I am following their development guide: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/microservices-demo/blob/master/docs/development-guide.md

After I successfully set up minikube (using virtualbox driver, but I tried also hyperkit, however the results were the same) and execute `skaffold run`, after some time it will end up with following error:

```
Building [shippingservice]...
Sending build context to Docker daemon    127kB
Step 1/14 : FROM golang:1.15-alpine as builder
 ---> 6466dd056dc2
Step 2/14 : RUN apk add --no-cache ca-certificates git
 ---> Running in 0e6d2ab2a615
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
WARNING: Ignoring https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/main: DNS lookup error
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
WARNING: Ignoring https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/community: DNS lookup error
ERROR: unable to select packages:
  git (no such package):
    required by: world[git]
Building [recommendationservice]...
Building [cartservice]...
Building [emailservice]...
Building [productcatalogservice]...
Building [loadgenerator]...
Building [checkoutservice]...
Building [currencyservice]...
Building [frontend]...
Building [adservice]...
unable to stream build output: The command '/bin/sh -c apk add --no-cache ca-certificates git' returned a non-zero code: 1. Please fix the Dockerfile and try again..
```

The error message suggest that DNS does not work. I tried to add `8.8.8.8` to `/etc/resolv.conf` on a minikube VM, but it did not help. I've noticed that after I re-run `skaffold run` and it fails again, the content `/etc/resolv.conf` returns to its original state containing `10.0.2.3` as the only DNS entry. Reaching the outside internet and pinging `8.8.8.8` form within the minikube VM works.

Could you point me to a direction how can possible I fix the problem and learn on how the DNS inside minikube/kubernetes works? I've heard that problems with DNS inside Kubernetes cluster are frequent problems you run into.

Thanks for your answers!

Best regards,
Richard

Comment: What versions of `minikube` and `scaffold` do you use? I want to try to reproduce it on my machine

Comment: skaffold: v1.23.0, minikube: v1.18.1

Comment: Was it just the `shippingservice` image that failed?  Does it work if you try minikube's `docker` driver?  There have been issues with VirtualBox DNS previously (https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/3606).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tried it with docker driver, i.e. `minikube start --driver=docker`, and it works. Thanks Brian!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like issue was resolved for OP but if one is using docker inside minikube then below suggestion worked for me.

Ref: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/10830

```
minikube ssh
$>sudo vi /etc/docker/daemon.json
# Add "dns": ["8.8.8.8"]
# save and exit
$>sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Comment: I want this to work so bad.. doesn't update /etc/resolv.conf though, which keeps getting overwritten if I update it with vi.