# Minikube - unable to access updates.jenkins.io

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, minikube

I am learning Kubernetes, by following the course, https://www.udemy.com/course/kubernetes-microservices/

When i try to build an image, using the file https://github.com/fleetman-ci-cd-demo/jenkins, using minikube's docker daemon. it fails due to the below reason

*curl: (6) Could not resolve host: updates.jenkins.io*

I logged into minikube shell as well and did a ping, it didn't work

```
    ping updates.jenkins.io
    PING updates.jenkins.io (52.202.51.185): 56 data bytes
    --- updates.jenkins.io ping statistics ---
68 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
```

I am able to reach google.com from minikube shell.

Please let me know how can i fix this?

The build log

```
    WARN: install-plugins.sh is deprecated, please switch to jenkins-plugin-cli
Creating initial locks...
Analyzing war /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war...
Registering preinstalled plugins...
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: updates.jenkins.io
The command '/bin/sh -c /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh workflow-aggregator &&     /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh github &&     /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh ws-cleanup &&     /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh greenballs &&     /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh simple-theme-plugin &&     /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh kubernetes &&     /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh docker-workflow &&     /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh kubernetes-cli &&     /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh github-branch-source' returned a non-zero code: 6
```

Comment: Do you need to set a proxy to get out?

Comment: I can see the `coredns` pod running in minikube

Comment: @Umar Have you managed this to work? If not, that looks like `dns` issue since `curl code 6` means that it wasn't able to resolve the host name. Please dns follow troubleshooting steps [described here - kubernetes official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/). Let me know what you find.

Comment: Fixed it by changing the VM,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67488003/how-to-resolve-dns-lookup-error-when-trying-to-run-example-microservice-applicat

Answer (score 2):

I think it's the container that has an issue with connecting to the Internet. I ran into the same problem with Jenkins running in Docker.

I restarted Docker with `sudo service docker restart`, and solved my problem.

Now if you're concerned with the depracated warning:

```
WARN: install-plugins.sh is deprecated, please switch to jenkins-plugin-cli
```

You may refer to [Jenkins' Docker image guide](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/ebb29a040aca944474542400a34f48e1eb8fa628/README.md#preinstalling-plugins). Cut to the chase, you need to replace the RUN command in Dockerfile.
From something like:

```
RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh < /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
```

to:

```
RUN jenkins-plugin-cli -f /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
```

Even with `jenkins-plugin-cli`, I faced a similar problem of reaching to Jenkins plugin server. It shows

```
Error getting update center json
```

In my case, it was solved by the same method, just restarting Docker service.

Comment: I fixed this by using docker as my virtual machine instead of virtual box based on this link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67488003/how-to-resolve-dns-lookup-error-when-trying-to-run-example-microservice-applicat
https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/10830

Answer (score 0):

Try with `curl` command , some website disable the ping for security reasons

Comment: Able to access the website using curl. But why the docker build is failing with `returned a non-zero code: 6`. How do i fix that?